# Django EnumField for Python3 and DRF support

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, enums, django-rest-framework

I need EnumField for my Django models. I have tried [django-enumfield](https://github.com/5monkeys/django-enumfield). But it's not supporting with Django 1.10. I also tried this [django-enumfields](https://github.com/hzdg/django-enumfields). But this is not supported with Django REST Framework.

My use case,

```
# models.py
role = EnumField(UserRoleEnum, default=UserRoleEnum.STUDENT)

# enums.py
class UserRoleEnum(Enum):
  STUDENT = 0
  TEACHER = 1
  ADMIN = 2
```

Comment: I was migrating from a plain choice to [django-enumfields](https://github.com/hzdg/django-enumfields) and now I also got a problem with DRF.  In short, I can get the field serialized properly (GET and SET) by also using [drf-enum-field](https://github.com/seebass/drf-enum-field).  But when I tried to add filter, it breaks again.

Comment: See [django-enumfields DRF docs](https://github.com/hzdg/django-enumfields#django-rest-framework-integration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** After 3 days. No answer. :(

I used a like that,

**enums.py**

```
class MyEnum:
    ADMIN = 0
    NORMAL = 1

USER_ENUM_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'ADMIN'),
    (0, 'NORMAL')
)
```

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(choices=MyEnum.USER_ENUM_CHOICES, max_length=1, ...)
```

**Note:** For simple case it's not a bad idea.